# Comentarios con Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

me preguntaba como puedo hacer que un comentario de una publicación se comente en tiempo real, es decir que cuando el usuario publique su comentario se guarde automáticamente en la página sin recargar

Comment: Deberias mirar acerca de ajax

Comment: puedes usar ajax: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SS8PJ7_9.6.1/com.ibm.etools.webtoolscore.doc/topics/cajax.html